# LaTeX symbol for gas station pump?

Tags: symbols

I may be able to use [this Unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26fd/index.htm) (⛽) for gas pumps with XeLaTeX, but I am looking for a package that provides such a symbol. Or any other native LaTeX approach?

Comment: After seeing ALL sorts of symbols [here](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) at pp. 118-205, and not spotting this one, I am afraid that no, that symbol is not offered by a font package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I went to the place you pointed and downloaded the image as fuel_pump.png.  Then I create a macro that scales it to the current `\strut` size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,graphicx}
\newcommand\fuelpump{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{fuel_pump}}{\strut}}
\begin{document}
normalsize pump: \fuelpump

\LARGE or LARGE: \fuelpump
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Instead of .png, I saved the .svg file as .pdf and used it. Works great!

Answer (score 8):

The only font I have that provides the glyph is Symbola that you can download from http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\symbolafont}{Symbola}

\newcommand{\gaspump}{{\symbolafont\symbol{"26FD}}}

\begin{document}

This is the symbol for a gas pump: \gaspump

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by "The only font I have that...". Did you create that package?

Comment: @manooooh The font is available to my OS because I installed it. i checked with a utility that shows Unicode characters and tells what available fonts have it.

Answer (score 3):

The symbol that I'm attaching is the pump of a gas station using `fontawesome5` package without to use Unicode characters.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
This is a symbol of gas-pump using fontawesome5: 
\faGasPump
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may also use the `coloremoji` package to get a full-color version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{coloremoji}

\newcommand\fuelpump{⛽}

\begin{document}
⛽{\fuelpump}^^^^26fd
\end{document}
```

Comment: Spectacular is the use of unicode with coloremoji package. But exists a pdf documentation? I have not find it.

Comment: @Sebastiano Just the `readme.md`, so far as I know.